# Error printing elements from a an array of pointers in MIPS

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, mips

I've been having trouble understanding what's going wrong in this code. I'm manipulating a pre-built array of strings here using an array of pointers. Additionally, the array of strings have to be placed on 32-byte border, hence the .align 5 preceding each string.

It's part of a larger set but this is the area with the relevant issue:

```
.data
            .align 2
    dataAddr:   .space 64       # allocating space for pointers
            
            .align 5
    dataName:   .asciiz "Apple"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Banana"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Zucchini"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Pickle"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Dragonfruit"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Carrot"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Pepper"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Cauliflower"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Orange"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Watermelon"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Potato"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Corn"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Plum"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Lettuce"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Mango"
            .align 5
            .asciiz "Peach"

    space:      .asciiz " "     # string for spaces
    start:      .asciiz "Initial array is: \n"
    printStart: .asciiz "[ "
    printFinish:    .asciiz "] \n"

.text

main:
initializePointersPrep:
    li $t0, 0       # set t0 to 0
    la $t1, dataName    # set t1 to address of array
    la $t2, dataAddr    # set t2 to address of pointer array

startCode:
    sw $t1, ($t2)       # store the word from dataName[i] in dataAddr[i]
    add $t2, $t2, 4     # move to dataAddr[i+1]
    addi $t1, $t1, 32   # move to dataName[i+1]
    add $t0, $t0, 1     # set iterator i to next location
    ble $t0, 16, startCode  # check if i has reached the end of the list (16)
    
    li $v0, 4       # print string
    la $a0, start       # load the start message
    syscall         # diplay to user
    
    jal print       # prints initial array

    j exit          # jump to exit

print:
printPrep:
    la $t0, dataAddr
    li $t1, 16
    li $t2, 0
    la $a0, printStart  # load the start of print [
    syscall         # diplay to user

printLoop:
    lw $a0, 0($t0)
    syscall
    
    la $a0, space
    syscall
    
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    bge $t2, $t1, printEnd
    j printLoop

printEnd:
    la $a0, printFinish # load the end of print ]
    syscall         # diplay to user
    
    jr $ra
    
exit:
    li $v0, 10      # end program/exit
    syscall
```

When I run this I get

```
Initial array is: 
[ @e Banana Zucchini Pickle Dragonfruit Carrot Pepper Cauliflower Orange Watermelon Potato Corn Plum Lettuce Mango Peach ] 

-- program is finished running --
```

Everything seems fine, except for the "@e", which I'm unsure of how to remedy. From my own testing, the issue doesn't happen when I limit my array to 15 elements. Also, the the first 5 characters are replaced by the "@", so a string of "Hi" produces "@", but a string "ABCDEFGH" produces "@FGH". How can I fix the issue so I don't receive the incorrect first element? Thank You.

Comment: Just a common off-by-one error. `ble $t0, 16, startCode` runs from 0 to 16 inclusive  but that's of course 17 elements. The extra pointer will be overwriting the first string because it just happens to follow in memory. Fix: use `blt`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be align 4 rather than align 5?